# How to order the columns for good presentation?

Tags: tables

In the picture is shown the results obtained by this code, I tried using one single tabular environment (`{ccc@{\qquad}ccc@{\qquad}ccc}`), but that did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mutavel}
\usepackage\[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate\]{mcode}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx} % <---- these are needed

\newcommand{\tsub}\[1\]{_{\text{\normalfont #1}}}
\newcommand{\where}\[1\]{%
    \hspace*{\fill}%
    \parbox\[b\]{\textwidth-\widthof{где }}{%
        \makebox\[0pt\]\[r\]{где }\ignorespaces#1%
    }\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
}
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker={,},
    %output-exponent-marker=\mathrm{e},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}\[!h\]
    \caption{Поляра}
    \label{tab:polar}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    $C_{ya}$ & -1.0 & -0.9 & -0.8 & -0.7 & -0.6 & -0.5 & -0.4 & -0.3 & -0.2 & -0.1 \\ \hline
    $C_{xa}$ & 0.09935 & 0.08661 & 0.07546 & 0.06591 & 0.05795 & 0.05159 & 0.04682 & 0.04365 & 0.04207 & 0.04209 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
     0,0 & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.9 & 1,0\\ \hline
     0,0437 & 0.0469 & 0.0517 & 0.0581 & 0.06609 & 0.07567 & 0.08685 & 0.09963 & 0.114 & 0.13 & 0,1475\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.6 & 1.7 & 1.8 & 1.9 & 2.0 \\ \hline
    0.1667 & 0.1874 & 0.2098 & 0.2337 & 0.2592 & 0.2864 & 0.3151 & 0.3454 & 0.3773 & 0.4108 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 & 2.4 & 2.5 & 2.6 & 2.7 & 2.8 & 2.9 & 3.0 \\ \hline
    0.4459 & 0.4826 & 0.5209 & 0.5608 & 0.6023 & 0.6453 & 0.69 & 0.7363 & 0.7841 & 0.8336 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}]
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I would swap rows and columns,using a table with 12 rows and 8 columns

Answer (score 4):

You can put the values in a single table in four rows, for -1, 0, 1 and 2 respectively. The issue with this is that you include both -1.0 and 3.0 in the table, which means you cannot really align it nicely - in the attempt below I have added the next number to the end of each line (to accomodate 3.0) and the number is omitted from the start of the next line.

Now the table becomes rather wide, I have shifted both the table itself and the caption to the left, with `\advance\leftskip-1.5cm` (for the table) and `\captionsetup{margin={-1.5cm,0pt}}` (for the caption). Note that `\captionsetup` comes from the `caption` package but in this case `\usepackage{caption}` is not necessary because `mutavel` already loads it.

To improve the appearance of the empty cells a bit a combination of multirows, multicolumns and centerlines is used from the `multirow` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mutavel}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\advance\leftskip-1.5cm
\captionsetup{margin={-1.5cm,0pt}}
    \caption{Поляра}
    \label{tab:polar}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    $C_{ya}$ & -1.0 & -0.9 & -0.8 & -0.7 & -0.6 & -0.5 & -0.4 & -0.3 & -0.2 & -0.1 & 0.0\\ \hline
    $C_{xa}$ & 0.09935 & 0.08661 & 0.07546 & 0.06591 & 0.05795 & 0.05159 & 0.04682 & 0.04365 & 0.04207 & 0.04209 & 0.0437\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{6}{*}{}} & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.6 & 0.7 & 0.8 & 0.9 & 1.0\\ \cline{3-12}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & 0.0469 & 0.0517 & 0.0581 & 0.06609 & 0.07567 & 0.08685 & 0.09963 & 0.114 & 0.13 & 0.1475\\ \cline{3-12}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & 1.1 & 1.2 & 1.3 & 1.4 & 1.5 & 1.6 & 1.7 & 1.8 & 1.9 & 2.0\\ \cline{3-12}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & 0.1667 & 0.1874 & 0.2098 & 0.2337 & 0.2592 & 0.2864 & 0.3151 & 0.3454 & 0.3773 & 0.4108\\ \cline{3-12}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & 2.1 & 2.2 & 2.3 & 2.4 & 2.5 & 2.6 & 2.7 & 2.8 & 2.9 & 3.0\\ \cline{3-12}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} & 0.4459 & 0.4826 & 0.5209 & 0.5608 & 0.6023 & 0.6453 & 0.69 & 0.7363 & 0.7841 & 0.8336 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]